# Fedora 30 cloud-init unable to render networking error

Tags: kvm-virtualization, fedora, proxmox, cloud-init

I created a Fedora 30 template on Proxmox with KVM virtualization.
When I create a VM from template and start it with cloud-init drive configured properly, I get unable to render networking error.
NetworkManager service is enabled and running.
How do I fix this?

[image: Fedora 30 Cloud-init unable to redner networking]

Edit:
This might be the issue.
https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/cloud-init-wrong-ip-in-eth0-when-fedora29-30.49137/#post-229610

Comment: How exactly did you create this Fedora 30 template? You probably should not make your own, but use [one provided by Fedora](https://alt.fedoraproject.org/cloud/) (for Proxmox, use the Openstack image).

Comment: Installed Fedora 30 minimal and then group of packages called standard. I installed cloud-init and used this commands: https://github.com/rharmonson/richtech/wiki/CentOS-7-1511-Minimal-oVirt-Template I also ran the commands which sys-unconfig contains. I also enabled predictable device names https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Cloud-Init_FAQ#Step_2:_System_preparation

Comment: FWIW I just tested the qcow2 image provided by Fedora. And it pretty much "just worked". The only issue was that the static IP that should have been set by Proxmox (via cloud-init) did not get applied. Initially I thought that it may be because of "predicable interface names", however, it defaults to eth0 (as per the screenshot) - so no idea there. Regarding your issue, I suggest that you try mounting both your image and the default qcow2 and compare initial network config for differences.